Не работает кнопка блокировки строки таблицы после поиска и обновления данных в React.js
Не работают кнопки после обновления данных при поиске. Мой код:
`const onLockModal = (): void => {
const row = refRows.current.find((it: any) => it.dataset.id === modalLock.current);
const item = refItems.current.find((it: any) => it.dataset.id === modalLock.current);
setModalLock((v: any) => ({...v, open: false}));

if (row) {
    (row as any).classList.toggle(s.disabled);
}

if (item) {
    (item as any).classList.toggle(s.disabled);
}

};
`
После результата поиска, кнопка больше не меняет класс у элемента
`
<TableRowAgent
      ref={(r: never) => !refRows.current.includes(r) && refRows.current.push(r)}
      data={it}
      setUnLock={setModalLock}
      key={it.id}
      onDraw={onToggleAgent}
      current={it.id}
    />

`
Это происходит когда меняются данные после поиска.
Может я не правильный подход выбрал, что после поиска меняются данные и нужно по другому сделать.
